# Execute jQuery on element's event listener and also on page load?

Tags: jquery

I dont know if its relevant but im using the jQuery Cycle 2 plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

The following code executes after a slide has transitioned. Its working perfectly but I need the code to also be run on page load (before any slides have transitioned). How can I modify the code below to make this happen?

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', function( event, opts ) {

    setTimeout(function() {

        var oldURL = window.location.hash;

        var final_url="";
        final_url=oldURL.replace('#', '');
        history.pushState('data', '', final_url);

         console.log('test 2');
    }, 1);

});
```

Comment: F.e. put the code into a function, and assign that to both events …?

Comment: What is the purpose of the timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name the function and refer to it.

```
var cycleFn = function( event, opts ) {
    setTimeout(function() {

        var oldURL = window.location.hash;

        var final_url="";
        final_url=oldURL.replace('#', '');
        history.pushState('data', '', final_url);

        console.log('test 2');
    }, 1);
};

$(window).on('load', cycleFn);
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', cycleFn);
```

Comment: Lol, you beat me on this one :) +1

Comment: @SunnyRGupta it happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. Define the repeating content as a function, then use it whenever you want.

```
function theFunction(){
setTimeout(function() {

        var oldURL = window.location.hash;

        var final_url="";
        final_url=oldURL.replace('#', '');
        history.pushState('data', '', final_url);

         console.log('test 2');
    }, 1);
}

$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', function( event, opts ) {
theFunction();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
theFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

call on pageload:

```
 window.onload = function{CycleSlideshowFn();}
```

call on event handler:

```
     $('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', function(){
        CycleSlideshowFn();
     ));
```

Your Function:

```
function CycleSlideshowFn(){
setTimeout(function() {

        var oldURL = window.location.hash;

        var final_url="";
        final_url=oldURL.replace('#', '');
        history.pushState('data', '', final_url);

         console.log('test 2');
    }, 1);
}
```